# ContactsContract Overview in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I was just going through the ContactsContract API in Android and I am stuck with the overview part of it.

Then I got this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider but I am still having difficulty understanding Contacts in android.

Can any of you provide me with links or explanation what is a Contact is, in Android perspective, for me it is just the number we save on our phone but I now know it is some thing more. Please explain to me (or provide link to a simpler or clearer explanation which is not the android documentation itself) what these three tables contain as I am unable to understand it from the docs.

1. ContactsContract.Contacts table
2. ContactsContract.RawContacts table
3. ContactsContract.Data table

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in many answers before in various phrasing:

The Contacts DB is organized in three main tables:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

Usually what happens is that an app (e.g. Google, Whatsapp, Linkedin) that wishes to create a new contact will create a new row in the `RawContacts` table that will usually contain just a name, and then use that row's _ID to add rows into the `Data` table for phones, emails, addresses, photos, etc.

Android will then either create a new row in `Contacts` to assign to that new raw-contact (i.e. a new contact was created), or if it decides that raw-contact contain similar enough information to an existing contact, will have an existing contact row assigned to that new raw-contact (i.e. the new information will be added to an existing contact).

The "assigning" part is done like this - each row in `Data` has a column `RAW_CONTACT_ID` which tells the contacts app which raw-contact does this info belong to, and each row in `RawContacts` has a column `CONTACT_ID` which tells the contacts app which row in `Contacts` this raw-contact belong-to.

So to get information on contact with _ID = 1234, you could first query info from `Contacts` where `_ID = 1234`, then query more info from `RawContacts` where `CONTACT_ID = 1234`, then query for more info from `Data` where `RAW_CONTACT_ID IN (X)` where X is the list of raw-contact ids you found previously.

The `Data` table also has a `CONTACT_ID` column, so you can basically skip the `RawContact` query, and get all the data (phones, emails, etc.) directly from the contact-id.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: Thank you, just the kind of explanation I was looking for.