# How to feed Android Contacts with data provided from my APK

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

What I am looking for is some **minimal example** (or tutorial) that shows how to implement Android APK (application) which is capable for providing some data into the `Contact List` of the phone (where the APK is installed).

Let's say I might have a DataBase with `Names` and `Phone_Numbers` and some `Additional_Info`.

What I would like to achieve is that when the APK gets installed on the phone the user is able to see the corresponding `Name` in case anyone mentioned called.
Moreover the `Name` and the `Additional_Info` shall appear also in the default `Contact List` next to the corresponding `Phone_Number` (quite similar like the [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/) APK or [Facebook Messenger](https://www.messenger.com/) APK does).

ps: I do prefer [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) but will also understand [Java](http://www.java.com/) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding contacts to Android requires apply and batch of operations:

1. Insert a new `RawContact`
2. Insert a list of `Data` items to that `RawContact`

Here's an example of how to add a single contact with some data: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#ContactBasics

However, in most cases inserting a standalone contact if not good practice, there are most steps you should take:

1. Create an `ACCOUNT_TYPE` & `ACCOUNT_NAME` for your app
2. Create a `SyncAdapter` / `WorkManager` that will continuously make sure the contacts set of your app and the contacts on the device are in-sync
3. Insert/update your `RawContacts` and their `Data` items using the above `SyncAdapter` / `WorkManager`

Here are some useful tutorials you should read:

- https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter
- https://stephen-chen.medium.com/android-account-sync-adapter-and-contacts-contract-database-983281be4847
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider

Make sure you understand the structure of the Contacts DB in Android, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966466/819355) for a simple overview.